# using 100+ EditTexts in Android Studio causes to lag the application

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I want to use 100+ edittexts in android studio but when I add 100+ edittexts, on application start, it lags for a while, once it renders then it is ok but the lag duration depends on the device specs so Is there an any efficient way to use 100+ edittexts in android studio without any lag or performance drop?

Comment: what type of application you are making?

Comment: it's a simple app taking user input (100+ input in numeric form i.e. 20, 10 etc) data and uploading to server.

Comment: use `For Loop` to get `userInput` as much time as you want. Why use 100 editText? Just use `For Loop` and get `UserInput` and store it to `String Buffer` or upload it in real time to Server.

Comment: I need to make a static UI so user can input value against each unique item and then save it on the server, so later on app can fetch and show the saved values in those edittexts while having the functionality to change values at any given time.

Comment: If you just want to show saved data to a user. Use `SharedPreference` to save and show again to users if they open your app again. If I can know what type of your app then I can suggest to you the best method.

Comment: I need to use 100+ edittexts in android studio - compulsory

but using 100+ edittexts in a conventional way makes the app laggy, so is there any efficient way to use or create custom views to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use hashmap or looping statements to make edittext. It is better to call api for saving and retrieving data instead of local.